# Story Problem: Algebra

Tags: problem-solving

A teacher gave a test, and most of his students did poorly. The teacher decided to let the students correct the questions they got wrong for 70% credit. One student corrected 80% and received a final score of 85%. What was this students initial score before corrections?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Simply pasting an assignment is no proper way to ask a question here.

Answer (score 2):

Let $c$=the correct answers originally.

Let $w$=the wrong answers originally.

Let $s$=the original score.

I will express percentages as decimals.

$s=\frac c {c+w}$ (Because $c+w$ is the total number of answers.)

The student corrected $.8w$ answers. He got back $.7 \times (.8w)$ points. He still had his $c$ points. This means that
$$ \frac {.7 \times (.8w)+c} {c+w} = .85$$
I quick plug into [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28.8%28w%29.7%2bc%29/%28c%2bw%29=.85%20and%20s=c/%28c%2bw%29%20solve%20for%20s) gets us $\frac {29} {44}=65.\overline{90}\% \approx $66%

That student was a failure.